# Is Test Driven Development possible in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, tdd

Is TDD (Test Driven Development) impossible since testing compose requires that the UI to be tested already exists?
Or are you creating a FakeScreen and testing it?

Comment: Can you please clearify "testing compose requires that the UI to be tested already exists". As far as I understand your question TTD is possible in Jetpack Compose: You can use e.g. Roborazzi screenshot testing. You can also supply your UI with fake data in order to test it without logic.